# Why does the scanner still run even though expression equates to false

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I've come across an issue with my scanner functionality. Even after entering "exit" in the terminal, the scanner keeps running. My suspicion is that this behavior is linked to the `revertState()` function inside of the implementation of `hasNext()`, but I'm not sure.

```
   String cmd;
    do {
        cmd = scanner.nextLine();
        // ...
        }
        System.out.printf("%b%n", !cmd.equals("exit"));
    } while(scanner.hasNext() && !cmd.equals("exit"));
```

However, rearranging the statement to `!cmd.equals("exit") && scanner.hasNext()` works, because scanner.hasNext() will not be invoked, thanks to the short-circuit evaluation.

I would also like to know how the `hasNext()` function is blocking this whole process.

Comment: @Sören thanks that answers my question. But I'm still curious how its possible to implement something like that so that the while loop is kind of discarded.

Comment: You don't need to check `scanner.hasNext()` - just use `while(!cmd.equals("exit"))`

Comment: @Sören Yes he does. What if the user types ctrl/d or ctrl/z instead of 'exit'?

Comment: @OP It is because `hasNext()` blocks. NB You should be using `hasNextLine()`, not `hasNext()`, as you are calling `nextLine()`, not `next()`.

Comment: user207421, `hasNextLine()` blocks just as much. Your advice is misleading here.

Comment: @rzwitserloot Only if you think the part after NB is part of a solution. That's not what 'NB' means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My suspicion is that this behavior is linked to the revertState() function inside of the implementation of hasNext(), but I'm not sure.

No, it's down to your misunderstanding of what these things *mean*.

`Scanner` wraps a resource - in your case, `System.in`. **`System.in` is NOT the keyboard**. It's 'standard in', and who knows what that is. It might be the keyboard. It might be a file. It might be nothing. Try it: `java -cp myClasspath com.foo.MyApp <somefile.txt` and now `System.in` represents the contents of that file.

### The crucial difference between files and keyboard

The concept 'it has ended' doesn't really apply to keyboards. However, it would to files: Once the file you are piping into a process has reached its end, that is it; it has ended **forever**. It is possible for the code to realize: No data is there. Will ever be there. For the rest of time.

In contrast a keyboard **does not end** (well, there's CTRL+D/CTRL+Z but let's leave explicitly 'closing the keyboard' out of it, clearly you aren't thinking of this if you ask this question).

*You wrote your code assuming that it will; that's where your mistake is.*

Your code, after the user types 'exit' and hits enter, asks: "Hey, is there another token?" via `hasNext()`. The answer is: **Who knows** - maybe. Maybe there will be one 5 minutes from now. The question **cannot be answered (yet)** by the system. You thought, perhaps, that `hasNext()` will wait a few seconds for the user to act and then draw the conclusion: Eh, nah, the user appears done. Or possibly that it has a crystal ball and attempts to scan the user's brain to find out if the user feels they are done - which, hopefully by putting it that way, should make you realize that's not how it works. Or you are thinking: `hasNext()` always returns instantly - it returns `true` if the user has already typed something, and false if the user hasn't yet typed something - what is false now could be true later.

That's.. just not how that function works. If `hasNext()` returns `false`, that's it. The way that API works, that **cannot change** - no new token means **no new token**. Not now. Not next minute. Not next year. Hence, why that method *does not return at all* - the user **might** type more.

What you want, presumably, is to just check for `!cmd.equals("exit")`. The reason 'swapping them around' works is that the `&&` operator 'short circuits': If evaluating the left hand side gives a definitive answer, the right hand side isn't evaluated at all, so, if `!cmd.equals("exit")` evaluates to `false` (because `cmd` *is* equal to `"exit"`), `scanner.hasNext()` isn't evaluated. That's a good thing, because evaluating `scanner.hasNext()` **hangs your app**.

Attempting to detect CTRL+D/CTRL+Z is kinda tricky; generally if you're writing an app designed to be an interactive command line thing, just detect 'exit' - i.e. just remove your `hasNext()`, it doesn't do what yo think it does and serves no purpose here.

Comment: Thank you for your extensive answer, it really helped. Now I understand the purpose of hasNext(), but how can such thing be implemented, that a single function makes it that it seems as everything else does not matter anymore. For me it seems as if this hasNext() function kind of implementes a listener for the scanner, and says I'm going to listen as long, until the user types CTRL+D or CTRL+Z.

Another strange behaviour, which @rph mentioned, was that if you type in "exit" two times, that then for some weird reason, the scanner is being terminated.

Comment: It's not 'weird'. After typing `exit` your application hangs on `.hasNext()`. Once you type a second thing (it can be anything, doesn't have to be `exit`), that method returns true, then your do/while condition checks: Was the last cmd `exit`? Yes, so, we exit. This further highlights how you should just remove `.hasNext()` - i'm unsure what you think that does, but, it just gets in the way.

Comment: `hasNext()` indeed is extremely pointless when getting keyboard input. It does nothing except block until the user types something then returns `true`. __It never, ever, returns `false`__. However, [A] `.hasNextInt()` could return false (if there's a non-int as next token), and for completeness sake, `hasNext()` should thus also be there, and [B] replace 'keyboard' with 'file' or any other terminating input source and all of a sudden `.hasNext()` is quite useful. It's a method that isn't for what you are doing (it's not _meant_ for apps that assume kbd input, like yours, so, don't call it).